# CONNECTION to Rinkeby showing false, contract not getting Deployed

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, solc, infura

**SOURCE CODE**

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');
var web3 = new Web3();
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/MY ACCESS TOKEN"));
const input = fs.readFileSync('CoincodeToken.sol');
console.log(input,"INPUT");
const output = solc.compile(input.toString(), 1);
const bytecode = output.contracts[':CoToken'].bytecode;
const abi = JSON.parse(output.contracts[':CoToken'].interface);
const myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,"MY CONTRACT ADDRESS");
const deploy = myContract.deploy({data:bytecode});
console.log(deploy,"DEPLOYED CONTRACT");
web3.eth.isMining()
    .then(console.log);
```

**RESPONSE**

```
{ send: { [Function: bound _executeMethod] request: [Function: bound _executeMethod] },
  encodeABI: [Function: bound _encodeMethodABI],
  estimateGas: [Function: bound _executeMethod],
  arguments: [],
  _method: 
   { inputs: [],
     payable: false,
     stateMutability: 'nonpayable',
     type: 'constructor',
     signature: 'constructor' },
  _parent: 
   Contract {
     currentProvider: [Getter/Setter],
     _requestManager: RequestManager { provider: [Object], providers: [Object], subscriptions: {} },
     givenProvider: null,
     providers: 
      { WebsocketProvider: [Function: WebsocketProvider],
        HttpProvider: [Function: HttpProvider],
        IpcProvider: [Function: IpcProvider] },
     _provider: 
      HttpProvider {
        **host: 'https://rinkeby.infura.io/MYACCESS TOKEN',
        timeout: 0,
        connected: false,**
        headers: undefined },
     setProvider: [Function],
     BatchRequest: [Function: bound Batch],
     extend: 
      { [Function: ex]
        formatters: [Object],
        utils: [Object],
        Method: [Function: Method] },
     clearSubscriptions: [Function],
     options: { address: [Getter/Setter], jsonInterface: [Getter/Setter] },
     defaultAccount: [Getter/Setter],
     defaultBlock: [Getter/Setter],
     methods: 
      { name: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        '0x06fdde03': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        'name()': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        approve: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        '0x095ea7b3': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        'approve(address,uint256)': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        totalSupply: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        '0x18160ddd': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        'totalSupply()': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        transferFrom: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        '0x23b872dd': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        'transferFrom(address,address,uint256)': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        standard: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        '0x5a3b7e42': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        'standard()': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        balanceOf: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        '0x70a08231': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        'balanceOf(address)': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        symbol: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        '0x95d89b41': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        'symbol()': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        transfer: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        '0xa9059cbb': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        'transfer(address,uint256)': [Function: bound _createTxObject] },
     events: 
      { Transfer: [Function: bound ],
        '0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef': [Function: bound ],
        'Transfer(address,address,uint256)': [Function: bound ],
        Approval: [Function: bound ],
        '0x8c5be1e5ebec7d5bd14f71427d1e84f3dd0314c0f7b2291e5b200ac8c7c3b925': [Function: bound ],
        'Approval(address,address,uint256)': [Function: bound ],
        allEvents: [Function: bound ] },
     _address: '0x8De117b37502CcCB116882fCb1a082dEbE698b90',
     _jsonInterface: 
      [ [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object] ] },
  _ethAccounts: 
   Accounts {
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not really read your code. Maybe try to prettify it a bit. Regardless I am deploying using ethers.js using a small library I wrote. Here is a simple code for you to deploy a truffle compiled contract.

```
const etherlime = require('etherlime');

const ICOTokenContract = require('./build/contracts/ICOToken.json');

const defaultConfigs = {
    gasPrice: 20000000000,
    gasLimit: 4700000
}

const deployer = new etherlime.JSONRPCPrivateKeyDeployer("Your private key", "Your node url + port", defaultConfigs);
const contractWrapper = await deployer.deploy(ICOTokenContract); // Make sure you call this method in an async function or use it as a promise without await
```

You can find more examples [here](https://github.com/LimeChain/etherlime)